# How can I convert a lambda of type Expression to something more specific?

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, expression-trees, linq-to-nhibernate

**Some background:**

My data access layer exposes an IQueryable to my service layer (I know it's naughty but it wasn't my decision). I'm using nHibernate in my data access layer and I want to specify properties to eager fetch BUT I don't want to use the NHibernate.Linq extension methods in the service layer. I'd be more comfortable hiding the fetch stuff behind an abstraction.

Here is that abstraction, a class called QueryBuilder.

It has a constructor to accept an IQueryable.

```
public QueryBuilder(IQueryable<TEntity> query)
{
    this.query = query;
}
```

And a method to accept the properties to eager fetch:

```
public QueryBuilder<TEntity> EagerFetch(params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] fetchExpressions)
{
    this.expressionPaths = this.ParseExpressions(fetchExpressions);
    return this;
}
```

ParseExpressions takes those fetchExpressions, breaks them up, removes duplicates and stores them as:

```
List<Expression>
```

Here's an example of how it's called:

```
Human human = this.humanRepository.Execute(
    new QueryBuilder<Human>(query).EagerFetch(h => h.LimbsList,
    h => h.LimbsList.First().DigitsList.First().Nail)).Single();
```

And the ParseExpressions method converts this to the following to be fetched:

```
x => x.LimbsList
x => x.DigitsList
x => x.Nail
```

So the next step is append these to my IQueryable. Eg.

```
this.query.Fetch(x => x.LimbsList).ThenFetchMany(x => x.DigitsList).ThenFetch(x => x.Nail);
```

**The Question**

How to I convert each Expression to whatever the nHibernate Fetch, FetchMany, ThenFetch and ThenFetchMany functions accept?

The compiler tells me:

> "The type arguments for method
>   'NHibernate.Linq.EagerFetchingExtensionMethods.Fetch<TOriginating,TRelated>(System.Linq.IQueryable<TOriginating>,
>   System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TOriginating,TRelated>>)'
>   cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments
>   explicitly."

I understand this, but I can't work out a way around it...

Comment: How do you figure out which fetch method should you call?

Comment: @svick If it's the first fetch then it's either Fetch or FetchMany based on whether the type implements ICollection. After that is's always ThenFetch or ThenFetchMany, again based on whether the type implements ICollection. (I've not coded that bit yet - but it should work)

Comment: I don't think that will work. For example, for `EagerFetch(x => x.Prop1, x => x.Prop2)`, it should be two `Fetch`es, and no `ThenFetch`.

Comment: Maybe are you willing to eager fetch for not having leveraged NHibernate lazy-loading optimizations. If you use them, you may eliminate the eager fetching, and so eliminate your current trouble with it. You may read my explanations on those optimizations [here](/a/36070727/1178314).

Comment: Ahh the moment one learns why repositories are an anti-pattern, IQueryable is a pipe-dream and everything you've been told is wrong. See you on the other side!

Comment: @cbp I'm with you there. I've just got to go through all of this to take others there too.

Comment: Show them how quick it would be if you just wrote the SQL statement, pushed the results into an object through Dapper (or at least NHibernate's CreateSqlQuery), and placed the whole lot directly in your controller where it is actually needed. Then ask them what exactly they are trying to achieve by adding layers of leaky abstraction, and impossible to performance tune, convoluted IQueryable code. In the eventuality that you 'move away from Sql Server'? Lol [do this]. So your DBA can 'easily find the queries'. Lol. Good luck when your DBA sees the crazy NHibernate code!